# How to get last inserted id in Python Cassandra?

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-python-driver

i am using python cassandra driver, i have searched that how to get last inserted id but couldn't find any solution except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453141/how-to-get-last-inserted-row-in-cassandra), but i want to get uuid or id not timestamp

can any body help me please ?

Comment: Cassandra requires a query-based modeling approach.  If you want to see the last-inserted row/id with Python (or whichever language), then you will need to design a table to support that kind of query and store that data yourself.  Cassandra does not have a way to do that intrinsically.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you really can't.  If this is a requirement you're better off creating the uuid locally and sending it to cassandra yourself.

Comment: yes i have done it with your mentioned method, thanks