# How to get inserted row immediately after query execution in cassandra?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I am trying to get last inserted row in cassandra but I am getting `undefined`

Here is how code looks for `insert`:

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['h1', 'h2'], keyspace: 'ks1' });

let query = "INSERT INTO users (id, name, email ) values (uuid(), ?, ?)";

client.execute(query, [ 'badis', 'badis@badis.com' ])
  .then(result => console.log('User with id %s', result.rows[0].id));
```

Comment: What does the primary key definition on your table look like?

Comment: Like this:  `id uuid PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: @Aaron sorry if my question was not clear enough. but everything is well structured and works for `select`. my issue is I want to get `id` and other infos of new inserted row.

Comment: I am getting this error: `(node:8140) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: So the error suggests that either result.rows doesn't exist or it is not an array. Could you console.log `result` and post back what you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember you are dealing with `NoSQL` ("non relational")

> If I were to run a `SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1` on this table, my
>   result set would contain a single row. That row would be the one
>   containing the lowest hashed value of username (my partition key),
>   because that's how Cassandra stores data in the cluster. I would have
>   no way of knowing if it was the last one added or not, so this
>   wouldn't be terribly useful to you.

[The workings are very different from those that you might be used to in `MySQL`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35461509/2976093)

If obtaining the last inserted row's information is needed for your system, then you will have to know it before you insert it.

[Generating UUID](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.5/features/datatypes/uuids/)

```
const Uuid = require('cassandra-driver').types.Uuid;
const id = Uuid.random();
```

Then you can use the `id` as another value for the prepared insert query

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['h1', 'h2'], keyspace: 'ks1' });

let query = "INSERT INTO users (id, name, email ) values (?, ?, ?)";

client.execute(query, [id, 'badis', 'badis@badis.com' ])
  .then(result => console.log('User with id %s', id));
```

Comment: Thank you ! does the generate Uuid is unique across all tables and across time ?